# webrtc: mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() returns empty deviceId

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm currently exploring webRTC and what I want to do is to get all the mediadevices info along with `deviceId` using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();` and then separate it out according to its kind attribute and allow user to choose which media device to use for specific kind. Like Show a dropdown of cameras found and allow user to choose which camera to use which is why i need deviceId of each device.

This is code I'm currently using to get mediadevices:

```
 const getConnectedDevices = async (type, callback) => {
  const mediaDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  console.log(mediaDevices);
  callback(mediaDevices.filter((device) => device.kind === type));
};
```

And this is what I got back as output:

```
[
    { 
      deviceId: ""
      groupId: "51081772b5c5df2dbcb2ca2b8ae36c5d693d816f8d4bf4039cdb15802b7ffc54"
      kind: "audioinput"
      label: ""
    },
    {
      deviceId: ""
      groupId: "2e7a46f912e66fea3b6af4822e427c02a7725c39d86194dccdf5b7993293d7da"
      kind: "videoinput"
      label: ""
    },
    {
     deviceId: ""
     groupId: "51081772b5c5df2dbcb2ca2b8ae36c5d693d816f8d4bf4039cdb15802b7ffc54"
     kind: "audiooutput"
     label: ""
    }
]
```

getting a empty deviceId all the time.
I also tried calling `await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( {video: true,audio: true,})` before `await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` but still got same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297972/navigator-mediadevices-enumeratedevices-returns-empty-labels/60300833#60300833

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() returns empty labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297972/navigator-mediadevices-enumeratedevices-returns-empty-labels)

Comment: no I saw that answer before posting this question and also tried calling await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( {video: true,audio: true,}) to request for permissions, but I still got similar result. I still got deviceId empty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns empty `deviceId`s now ahead of `getUserMedia` because tracking libraries were (and [still are](https://chromestatus.com/metrics/feature/timeline/popularity/1119)) calling `enumerateDevices` en masse to fingerprint people, with no intention of ever asking for camera or microphone.

The spec was reviewed by the [Privacy Interest Group (PING)](https://www.w3.org/Privacy/IG/), and, as a result, this *enumerate first* strategy (enumerating devices before asking the user for their camera or microphone) was deprecated, to improve user privacy. *This is true even in browsers that opt users into persistent permission.* (caveat: this last part got backed out in Chrome, so please go ★ [crbug 1101860](https://crbug.com/1101860)!)

All the big WebRTC sites already use a *device first* strategy instead (asking for camera or microphone first, then implementing device switching under ⚙️ options while live). So web compat of this breaking change was deemed acceptable.

In other words, ahead of `getUserMedia` resolving, you can only learn whether the user has no camera or no microphone. Those are the only two fingerprinting bits that remain (you won't see multiple devices listed).

> I also tried calling [getUserMedia] before, ... but still got same result.

Then you did something wrong,  because both `label`s and `deviceId`s are available then, to make device switching still work. See [WebRTC Samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/) for a demo. You can even still store those `deviceId`s and use them with `getUserMedia` on future visits, that part still works. You just can't enumerate them (track their presence) before asking for them with the `deviceId` constraint.

The operating assumption is that the most popular tracking libraries operate in the shadows, and won't risk ever actually prompting the user for their camera or microphone on behalf of their client sites.